# Encrypting private key in Python

Tags: python, openssl, pyopenssl, python-cryptography

I have a private key in DER format. I am trying to convert it to PEM and simultaneously encrypt the private key with a passphrase.

Here is the openssl command that I am using to convert and encrypt:

```sh
> openssl rsa -aes256 -inform der -in temp_key.der -outform pem -passout pass:<password>
```

I am trying to implement a similar logic in Python where I have the data for the key in-memory in DER format.
I want to change it to PEM, encrypt it and then store to a file.

I am not very well versed with Python's Crypto libraries and I am having a hard time to figure out the right way to convert and encrypt my key data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load a DER key and dump it as a password protected PEM key with help of [cryptography](https://github.com/pyca/cryptography) module as follows:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

private_key = serialization.load_der_private_key(
    der_data, # assuming that "der_data" variable contains your DER key
    password=None,
    backend=default_backend()
)

pem_encrypted = private_key.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(b'mypassword')
)

print(pem_encrypted.decode()) # -----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----...
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I reached at the same code. Check out my implementation in the answer below.

Answer (score 2):

Both other answers will work for you. Purely for variety, I shall add mine.
For RSA, I personally prefer to use `PyCryptodome`, for the reason it has more features in when it comes to the RSA cipher, and it's RSA instance is programmed in pure python.

This code should work for you:

```py
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

key = RSA.import(open('key.der', 'rb').read())

with open('key.pem', 'wb') as f:

    pem_key = key.export_key(passphrase='password')

    f.write(pem_key)
    f.close()
```

If you wanted, you could specify the output format of the exported key, but PyCryptodome currently defaults to PEM.

You can find thorough documentation for both libraries at https://cryptography.io and https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io respectively.

Comment: I think in the second code line you wanted to write
    RSA.import_key

Answer (score 1):

Used the [cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) module for python
This is the implementation I reached at

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.serialization import load_der_private_key
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization


key = load_der_private_key(
            der_data, password=None, backend=default_backend())

password_protected_key = key.private_bytes(encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
                                        format=serialization.PrivateFormat.TraditionalOpenSSL,
                                        encryption_algorithm=serialization.BestAvailableEncryption("password"))
```

Comment: If this answer works, add it as the selected answer.